# Dynamic function call for service in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on Angular2 project in which i need to generate dynamic function which will be able to call the service provided under the service class. The service class has some 10 get functions as the following.

eg:

my service class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class service {

  constructor() { }

  get function1(){
    return 1;
  }

  get function2(){
    return 2;
  }

  get function2(){
    return 3;
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a function which take parameter as the function name and return the corresponding answer.

eg:

my app.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {service} from "./service";

@Component({
      selector: 'app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
      providers : [service]
 })

 export class AppComponent(){

  constructor(private _service:service){}

  let one = getVal(function1); /// This should return 1
  let two = getVal(function2); /// this should return 2

  getVal(val){
     return this._service.val; // but i am getting error val not exist on type service
    }

}
```

Is their any solution for this since it will help me to reduce my code and performance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how you are differentiating each one

Comment: function names are different for all the functions

Comment: can you elaborate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`function1`, etc are not just 'get functions' - they are property accessor methods.

Instead, it likely should be

```
let one = getVal('function1');
```

and

```
getVal(val){
 return this._service[val];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A little difficult to to tell what you're asking, but this may help.

```js
class MyService {
 get function1() {
   return 1;
 }
  get function2() {
   return 2;
 }
  get function3() {
   return 3;
 }
}

const service = new MyService();

const getValFactory = service => name => service[name];
const getVal = getValFactory(service);

// Use strings, not unquoted function names.
console.log(getVal('function1'));
console.log(getVal('function2'));
console.log(getVal('function3'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "any" to bypass the TypeScript strong typing checking.

return (this.service as any)[val]

```js
class Service {
 constructor() {}
 get function1() {
  return 1;
 }
 get function2() {
  return 2;
 }
 get function3() {
  return 3;
 }
}

class AppComponent {
 constructor(private service: Service) {}
 getVal(val: string) {
  return (this.service as any)[val];
 }
}

const service = new Service();
const app = new AppComponent(service);
console.log(app.getVal("function1"));
console.log(app.getVal("function2"));
console.log(app.getVal("function3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to return the corresponding method with switch statement and bind(this).

**service.ts**

```
export class DynamicApiCallService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    dynamicMethods(method: string) {
        switch (method) {
            case 'one': return this.one.bind(this);
            case 'two': return this.two.bind(this);
            case 'three': return this.three.bind(this);
        }
    }

    one(id: string) {
        return this.http.get<any>(`one/${id}`);
    }

    two(id: string) {
        return this.http.get<any>(`two/${id}`);
    }

    three(id: string) {
        return this.http.get<any>(`three/${id}`);
    }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
this.dynamicApiCallService.dynamicMethods('one')(id).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    // Write your logic
})
```